# Why does my UIViewController with UITableView crash after quickly switching from a UITableView With MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mkmapview

In a section in my iOS app there is a view that lets the user select from a list of buses. When the user selects the bus, it takes them to a different view controller displaying the bus route on a map. Everything works perfectly unless for some reason the user selects the bus and then presses the back button in the route really fast, in which case it sometimes crashes the app (not always). When the crash happens, the bus selection view is visible, so it does get to that view. It crashes somewhere in there. This problem **only** occurs when the user presses the back button in the route view really fast. Otherwise there is no problem. The back button is connected as modal to the bus selection view controller.

**MapsViewController.h (this is where the user selects from list of buses)**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MapsViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *weekdayBusesNumbers;
    NSArray *saturdayBusesNumbers;
    NSArray *sundayBusesNumbers;

    NSArray *weekdayBusesNames;
    NSArray *saturdayBusesNames;
    NSArray *sundayBusesNames;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mapsTitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *selectABusLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

**MapsViewController.m (this is where the user selects from list of buses)**

```
#import "MapsViewController.h"
#import "GlobalVariables.h"
#import "RouteMapViewController.h"

@interface MapsViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.mapsTitleLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 33.5);
    self.selectABusLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 49, self.view.frame.size.width, 38);
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(-15, 87, self.view.frame.size.width+15, self.view.frame.size.height-87);
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, savedRouteTableViewSelectionHeightOffset) animated:NO];


    weekdayBusesNumbers = @[@"002", @"006"];
    weekdayBusesNames = @[@"Bus 002", @"Bus 006"];

    saturdayBusesNumbers = @[@"101", @"103"];
    saturdayBusesNames = @[@"Bus 101", @"Bus 103"];

    sundayBusesNumbers = @[@"300", @"303"];
    sundayBusesNames = @[@"Bus 300", @"Bus 303"];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0) // Weekday
        return weekdayBusesNumbers.count;

    else if(section == 1) // Saturday
        return saturdayBusesNumbers.count;

    else if(section == 2) // Sunday
        return sundayBusesNumbers.count;

    return 0;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    else
        [[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];


    UILabel *numberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 60, 40)];
    numberLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30];
    numberLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    numberLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;


    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width-numberLabel.frame.size.width-55, 40)];
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;


    if(indexPath.section == 0) // Weekday
    {
        numberLabel.text = weekdayBusesNumbers[indexPath.row];
        nameLabel.text = weekdayBusesNames[indexPath.row];
    }

    else if(indexPath.section == 1) // Saturday
    {
        numberLabel.text = saturdayBusesNumbers[indexPath.row];
        nameLabel.text = saturdayBusesNames[indexPath.row];
    }

    else if(indexPath.section == 2) // Sunday
    {
        numberLabel.text = sundayBusesNumbers[indexPath.row];
        nameLabel.text = sundayBusesNames[indexPath.row];
    }


    [cell.contentView addSubview:numberLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];


    return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
        currentMapViewing = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Weekday%@", weekdayBusesNumbers[indexPath.row]];

    else if(indexPath.section == 1)
        currentMapViewing = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Saturday%@", saturdayBusesNumbers[indexPath.row]];

    else if(indexPath.section == 2)
        currentMapViewing = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sunday%@", sundayBusesNumbers[indexPath.row]];


    savedRouteTableViewSelectionHeightOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    RouteMapViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RouteMapView"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}



- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}



- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if(section == 0)
        return @"        Monday to Friday";

    else if(section == 1)
        return @"        Saturday";

    else if(section == 2)
        return @"        Sunday";

    return @"";
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}



- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 40;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass: [UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]) {

        UITableViewHeaderFooterView* castView = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView*) view;
        castView.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [castView.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}

@end
```

**RouteMapViewController.h (this is where the route of bus is displayed on map)**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface RouteMapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    MKPolyline *routeLine;
    MKPolylineView* routeLineView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *busNumberTopLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *busNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *leftOfBusNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rightOfBusNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mapTypeSegmentedControl;

@end
```

**RouteMapViewController.m (this is where the route of bus is displayed on map)**

```
#import "RouteMapViewController.h"
#import "GlobalVariables.h"
#import "CustomAnnotationView.h"
@import CoreLocation;

@interface RouteMapViewController ()

@end

@implementation RouteMapViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.busNumberTopLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 33.5);
    self.busNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 49, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 38);
    self.busNameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    self.leftOfBusNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 49, 20, 38);
    self.rightOfBusNameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-20, 49, 20, 38);
    self.mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 87, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-87);
    self.mapTypeSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(self.mapTypeSegmentedControl.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height-36, 304, 29);


    MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}};

    if([currentMapViewing isEqualToString:@"Weekday002"])
    {
        self.busNumberTopLabel.text = @"002";
        self.busNameLabel.text = @"Bus 002";
        region.center.latitude = 52.500802;
        region.center.longitude = -86.965345;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.074971;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.088683;
    }

    else if([currentMapViewing isEqualToString:@"Weekday006"])
    {
        self.busNumberTopLabel.text = @"006";
        self.busNameLabel.text = @"Bus 006";
        region.center.latitude = 53.487891;
        region.center.longitude = -87.004044;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.033501;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.039619;
    }

    else if([currentMapViewing isEqualToString:@"Saturday101"])
    {
        self.busNumberTopLabel.text = @"101";
        self.busNameLabel.text = @"Bus 101";
        region.center.latitude = 52.502169;
        region.center.longitude = -85.966747;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.079915;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.094534;
    }

    else if([currentMapViewing isEqualToString:@"Saturday103"])
    {
        self.busNumberTopLabel.text = @"103";
        self.busNameLabel.text = @"Bus 103";
        region.center.latitude = 53.487662;
        region.center.longitude = -86.004759;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.029682;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.035102;
    }

    else if([currentMapViewing isEqualToString:@"Sunday300"])
    {
        self.busNumberTopLabel.text = @"300";
        self.busNameLabel.text = @"Bus 300";
        region.center.latitude = 51.469874;
        region.center.longitude = -87.010039;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.094139;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.111295;
    }

    else if([currentMapViewing isEqualToString:@"Sunday303"])
    {
        self.busNumberTopLabel.text = @"303";
        self.busNameLabel.text = @"Bus 303";
        region.center.latitude = 52.481819;
        region.center.longitude = -85.030556;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.088188;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.104282;
    }

    [self getAndSetInitialMap];
    [self.mapView setRegion:region];
}



- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.mapView removeFromSuperview];
    self.mapView.delegate = nil;
    self.mapView = nil;
}



- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"CustomViewAnnotation";
    CustomAnnotationView *customAnnotationView = (CustomAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    if(!customAnnotationView)
    {
        customAnnotationView = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotationImage:annotationIdentifier reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier annotationViewImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenStopPin.png"]];

        customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }

    return customAnnotationView;
}



- (void)getAndSetInitialMap
{
    switch(currentMapMode)
    {
        case 0:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;

        case 1:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;

        case 2:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [self.mapTypeSegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:currentMapMode];
}



- (IBAction)setMap:(id)sender
{
    switch(((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            currentMapMode = 0;
            break;

        case 1:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            currentMapMode = 1;
            break;

        case 2:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            currentMapMode = 2;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}



- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKOverlayView *overlayView = nil;

    if(overlay == routeLine)
    {
        routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:routeLine];
        routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;

        overlayView = routeLineView;
    }
    return overlayView;
}



- (void)mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView fullyRendered:(BOOL)fullyRendered
{
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:currentMapViewing ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                          error:NULL];


    NSCharacterSet *newlineCharSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
    NSArray *fileLines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:newlineCharSet];
    NSMutableArray *routeLatitudes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *routeLongitudes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for(int i=0; i<fileLines.count; i++)
    {
        MKPointAnnotation *pointToAdd = [stopInformationDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fileLines[i]]];

        [self.mapView addAnnotation:pointToAdd];

        if(i==0)
            [self.mapView selectAnnotation:pointToAdd animated:YES];

        [routeLatitudes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:pointToAdd.coordinate.latitude]];
        [routeLongitudes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:pointToAdd.coordinate.longitude]];
    }


    MKMapPoint* pointsArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * [routeLatitudes count]);
    for(int i = 0; i < [routeLatitudes count]; i++)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;
        workingCoordinate.latitude=[[routeLatitudes objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
        workingCoordinate.longitude=[[routeLongitudes objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
        MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(workingCoordinate);
        pointsArray[i] = point;
    }

    routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:[routeLatitudes count]];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:routeLine];
}

@end
```

**Crash**

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x37482f66 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x2cfe917a in __125-[UIPopoverController _presentPopoverFromRect:embeddedInView:usingViewForLayoutConstraints:permittedArrowDirections:animate:]_block_invoke416 ()
#2  0x2ca54940 in -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] ()
#3  0x2ca54558 in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] ()
#4  0x2ca5446e in -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] ()
#5  0x2c443046 in CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) ()
#6  0x0023f186 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#7  0x00242e9c in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF ()
#8  0x293ab888 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ ()
#9  0x293a9fa8 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#10 0x292f59a0 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x292f57b2 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#12 0x30ace1a8 in GSEventRunModal ()
#13 0x2ca80694 in UIApplicationMain ()
#14 0x00108d04 in main at HIDDEN……
```

Comment: that crash location is not helpful, i doubt anyone will understand the assembler code... What is the error message and what is the actual stack trace? And please only include the neccesary code!

Comment: There was no error message (at least I don't think so since nothing showed up in the debug as it normally does when a crash occurs). I have added the stack trace and I am not sure what is deemed the necessary code since I have no clue what is causing it so I thought better safe to include all of it. Thank you.

Comment: Well I have concluded the cause of the crash. It only crashes when selectAnnotation is animated. How can I avoid this crash and still have my selectAnnotation animated?